# Insufficient permissions error using Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files to google drive using below code

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/google/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
{
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  /*$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
  $files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();
  echo json_encode($files_list);*/

  $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle("test");
    $file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
          'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
          'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        ));

    echo "===".$fileId = $createdFile->id;
}
else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/google/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

and it is giving me insufficient permissions error.
Am i missing something?

I tried using Service account and it worked fine, Is Service account required to upload files using Google Drive API?

Comment: Where did you get your token (`$_SESSION['access_token']`) from? From the `OAuth2` mechanism with the same scopes and redirections?

Comment: first time $_SESSION['access_token'] is unset then i am making use of  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']) in oauth2callback.php to get access token. I am fetch list from gdrive using listFiles method, but not ble to insert

Comment: Then it might have sth to do with different scopes. Do you define other scopes when receiving the token then when trying to insert a file?